# Do different native apps running embedded chromium views share chromium resources?

Tags: testing, ipc, chromium, chromium-embedded

If I have multiple different native applications running on my computer which use some form of embedded Chromium (could be either CEF, Electron, or something similar) is there any sharing of Chromium messaging (inter-process communication or otherwise) or Chromium specific resources that gets shared between these applications?

**Extra unneeded details below this point for question context**

I am testing an application that I am working on that uses CEF which sometimes has UI update issues. I happened to also have Slack running in the background (which uses Electron) and noticed that occasionally that my application's UI would update/refresh when I got a Slack notification.

Since both applications technically use some form of embedded Chromium, I was worried that some of the behavior I was seeing in tests might be invalid due to behavior modification from other embedded Chromium applications if there is some kind of shared resource or messaging (like embedded Chromium in Slack potentially sending some kind of push update notification that causes Chromium in my application to refresh itself).

I remembered reading that Chromium was designed to have a main application process that then spawns independent render processes per window. I wasn't sure if each application using a form of embedded Chromium would then potentially share a main Chromium process or if each application gets their own sandboxed main Chromium process and the simultaneous updates I was seeing were merely a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally nothing has shared.

PS: By normally i mean that applications doesnt depend on third party plugins, and doesnt try to dynamically find chrome plugins, for example. Same for cache paths, i.e. applications have correctly configured cache paths instead of using any possible defaults.